# On-demand EC2 instance hourly usage report

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to see On-demand EC2 instance usage breakdown on per hour basis? The EC2 instance usage report at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-reports/home has options for breakdown by per day and per month.

Answer (score 0):

Activate your [Cost and Usage Report](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html) to receive detailed billing files in Amazon S3 that show all resources, with Resource IDs, down to an hourly basis.

See also: [AWS Cost and Usage Reports: Comprehensive and customizable reporting on your AWS costs and cost drivers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/aws-cost-and-usage-reports-comprehensive-and-customizable-reporting-on-your-aws-costs-and-cost-drivers/)